# mpirun with slurm : how to run multiple processes on a single CPU

Tags: mpi, cpu, slurm

I would like to write slurm batches (sbatch) to run several mpi applications. Thus I would like to be able to run something like that

```
salloc --nodes=1 mpirun -n 6 hostname
```

But I get this message :

> There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 6 slots
>   that were requested by the application:
>    hostname
>
> Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available for use.

The node has actually 4 CPUs. I therefore looking for something allowing more task per CPU but I cannot find the proper option.  I know that mpi alone is able to run several processes when physical resources are missing. I think the problem is on the slurm side. 
Do you have any suggestions/comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `srun` and supply the option `--overcommit`, e.g. like that:

test.job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=6
#SBATCH --overcommit

srun hostname
```

Run `sbatch test.job`

From `man srun`:

> Normally, srun will not allocate more than one process per CPU.   By  specifying `--overcommit` you are explicitly allowing more than one process per CPU.

Note depending on your cluster configuration this may or may not work also with `mpirun`, but I'd stick with `srun` unless you have a good reason not to.

An important **warning**: Most MPI implementations by default have **terrible performance** when running in overcommited. How to address that is a different, much more difficult, question.